# Loading an array of XML files with asynchronous XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, anonymous-function

I want to load an array of XML files, and store them in an array.

Code example:

```
var src = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ];
var dest = {};
for (var i in src) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", src[i], true);
    req.onreadystatechange = function(aEvt) {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            if (req.status == 200) {
                dump(i + "\n");
                dest[i] = req.responseXML;
            }
        }
    }
    req.send(null);
}
```

However, the dump result is always

> 3
>
> 3
>
> 3
>
> 3

It shows that the `i` referenced in callback is always the outer `i`, so the XML files cannot be stored correctly.

So, how to solve this issue? We have about 50 XML files to load and loading them one by one is not acceptable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Don't use `for..in` to loop over arrays. Use a normal `for` loop.
2. You make the typical mistake of creating a function in a loop. JavaScript has no block scope, only function scope, so `i` will always refer to the last element of the array you looped over when the functions you created are executed. They all have a reference to the **same** `i`. You can solve this by using an immediately executing function that returns a function (thus, capturing the value of `i`).
3. If you do this, you also have to capture a reference to `req`, otherwise it will always refer to the last generated XMLHttpRequest (the same reason as for `i`).

So one solution would be:

```
var src = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ];
var dest = {};
for (var i = src.length;i--;) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", xmlfile, true);
    req.onreadystatechange = (function(i, req) {
        return function(aEvt) {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                if (req.status == 200) {
                    dump(i + "\n");
                    dest[i] = req.responseXML;
                }
            }
        };
    }(i, req)); // capturing the current value/reference of i and req
    req.send(null);
}
```

@Spiny Norman's solutions might be more readable ;)

Comment: EXCELLENT .... but what if my for loop iterate many times (say 20) and each is network request, how can i actually delete / close all the other threads...

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
var src = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ];
var dest = {};
var loadXml = function(i) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", xmlfile, true);
    req.onreadystatechange = function(aEvt) {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            if (req.status == 200) {
                dump(i + "\n");
                dest[i] = req.responseXML;
            }
        }
    }
    req.send(null);
};

for (var x = 0; x < src.length; x++) {
    loadXml(x);
}
```

By the way, it seems you're always loading the same xmlfile, but I'm sure this is different in your actual code ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, but I am marking Felix Kling's solution as correct since it has more explanation.

Comment: One of the best answers in stack overflow...... Is there any way by which we can cancel all the requests... I mean, if the for loop runs 100 times is there any way (say on click of some button on UI) to stop / abort other requests which are still running... Thanks